# Apply chart template from local chart, not template file

Tags: excel, vba

I currently use this line to apply a chart template to many charts in my file (while looping through them):

```
cht.ApplyChartTemplate ("H:\Company\My Company\Stats\PChart Template.crtx")
```

This works fine - however, I would like to host a local chart in my file that can server as the "master" chart, and apply that theme to my charts - this way I can easily change the theme if/when needed.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.chart.applycharttemplate) for `.ApplyChartTemplate` only takes a filename argument - is there anyway to manipulate this to take a local chart instead? I haven't seen any workarounds in my searches.

Comment: I think it likely you will need to write something that can read the formatting of an existing chart and apply that to the chart of your choice. Things I have seen with OLEObjects, for example, still work with temp files.

Comment: You can use VBA to export the chart as a template, using a temporary file, then apply that exported template.  `myMasterChart.SaveChartTemplate ("C:\Temp\Chart1.crtx")`

Comment: @TimWilliams Oh that could work!

Comment: @TimWilliams Could you post your solution as an answer so I can mark as solved? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VBA to export the chart as a template, using a temporary file, then apply that exported template.

Eg.:

```
myMasterChart.SaveChartTemplate ("C:\Temp\Chart1.crtx")
```